# Laurent series of transformed exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, entire-functions

This exercise is from Conways Complex Analysis (Chapter 5, exercise 12)

> (a) Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and show that
> $$
> \exp \left\{\frac{1}{2} \lambda\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)\right\}=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\left(z^n+\frac{1}{z^n}\right)
> $$
> for $0<|z|<\infty$, where for $n \geq 0$
> $$
> a_n=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi e^{\lambda \cos t} \cos n t d t
> $$
> (b) Similarly, show
> $$
> \exp \left\{\frac{1}{2} \lambda\left(z-\frac{1}{z}\right)\right\}=b_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n\left(z^n+\frac{(-1)^n}{z^n}\right)
> $$
> for $0<|z|<\infty$, where
> $$
> b_n=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \cos (n t-\lambda \sin t) d t
> $$

---

I think the first one is already on StackExchange. I am rather interested in proving:

> There are uniquely determined integer functions $J_{n}$ such that for all $(z, \zeta) \in \mathbb{C} \times(\mathbb{C} \backslash 0)$ the equation $\exp \left(\frac{z}{2}\left(\zeta-\frac{1}{\zeta}\right)\right)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_{n}(z) \zeta^{n}$ holds.

This could mabe be done with Laurent development. The only question is how
one is to know that the $J_n$ are holomorphic.

Comment: Is what you are asking same as : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493427/laurent-series-of-the-function?rq=1 ?

Comment: For the existence of Laurent series, See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Existence_of_Laurent_Series . For a function holomorphic on a punctured disk, laurent series exists.

Comment: By above 2 comments we have that $J_n(z) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} cos(nt-z sin(t)) dt$

Answer (score 1):

The functions we are looking for are called Bessel functions. With
$$
\exp \left(\frac{z}{2}\left(\zeta-\frac{1}{\zeta}\right)\right)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_{n}(z) \zeta^{n}
$$
follows from Cauchy's integral formulas
$$
J_n(z)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|\zeta|=1} \frac{1}{\zeta^{n+1}} \exp\left(\frac{z}{2}\left(\zeta-\frac{1}{\zeta}\right)\right) d\zeta
$$
The integrand is an integer function in $z$, so $J_n(z)$ is also integer.
With $\zeta(t)=\exp(it)$, it follows that
$$
\begin{aligned}
J_n(z) & =\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \exp(-i(n+1)) \exp\left(\frac{z}{2}\left(\exp(it)-\exp(-it)\right)\right) \exp(it) d t\\\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \exp(-i n t) \exp(i z \sin t) d t 
 =\frac{1}{2 \pi} \underbrace{\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos (z \sin t-n t) d t}_{=: I_1}+\frac{i}{2 \pi} \underbrace{\int{-\pi}^\pi \sin (z \sin t-n t) d t}_{=: I_2} \\
& =\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \cos (n t-z \sin t) d t
\end{aligned}
$$
since the integrand of $I_1$ is even and that of $I_2$ is odd.
The exponential series yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\exp \left(\frac{z}{2}\left(\zeta-\frac{1}{\zeta}\right)\right) & =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k !}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^k\left(\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}(-1)^j \zeta^{k-2 j}\right) \\
& =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k !}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^k\left(\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}(-1)^{k-j} \zeta^{2 j-k}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
We are looking for the coefficient $J_n(z)$ of $\zeta^n$ in the Laurent series expansion. Rearrangement is allowed because of absolute convergence.
The first series representation yields for $n \geq 0$ (set $k=2 j+n$ ):
$$
J_n(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 j+n) !}\binom{2j+n}{j}(-1)^j\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2 j+n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k !(n+k) !}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{n+2 k} .
$$
The second row representation yields for $n<0$ (with $k=2 j-n)$ :
$$
J_n(z) =\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 j-n) !}\binom{2j-n}{j}(-1)^{j-n}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2 j-n}=(-1)^n \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^j}{(j-n) ! j !}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2 j-n}=(-1)^n J_{-n}(z) .
$$

---

Now I am not entirely sure about the holomorphy argument. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Existence_of_Laurent_Series laurent series for $exp(\frac{z}{2}(\zeta-\frac{1}{\zeta}))$ exists and since laurents series exists we have by [Laurent Series of the function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493427/laurent-series-of-the-function?rq=1)
:
$J_n(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} cos(nt-z sin(t)) dt$.